# Bash script missing ']' error

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a script to mount an usb device and cdrom drive automaticly when its plugged in. I had been trying to get this working with autofs (see https://superuser.com/questions/605896/automount-usb-pen-drive-and-cdrom-drive-on-plugin) but now trying to work with a script running at boot.

I think the logic is sound but I get `line 13: [: missing ']'`

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
 do
    if [ -b /dev/sda1 ]
       then
       mkdir /media/usb
       mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb
       while [ -b /dev/sda1]; do
         sleep 2
       done
       umount /media/usb
       rmdir /media/usb
    fi
    if [ -b /dev/cdrom ]
       then
       mkdir /media/cdrom
       mount /dev/sda1 /media/cdrom
       while [ -b /dev/cdrom]; do
         sleep 2
       done
       umount /media/cdrom
       rmdir /media/cdrom
    fi

    sleep 5
 done
```

And then script is launched from rc.local using `./path/to/script&`

Comment: `while [ -b /dev/sda1] => while [ -b /dev/sda1 ]`

Comment: Same issue 10 lines later at `while [ -b /dev/cdrom]; do`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a space here:

```
while [ -b /dev/cdrom]; do
                     ^
_____________________|
```

Comment: well that was one big 'doh' moment :/ thanks (shall mark answered after the 5 minutes)

Comment: @ZacPowell Happens to the best of us. :)

Comment: `[` is actually a (possibly built-in) command, not part of the shell's fundamental syntax. The last argument to the `[` command should be `]`. `/dev/cdrom]` is parsed as a single token. That's why the space is required.

Answer (score 1):

There's only a whitespace missing, instead of

```
while [ -b /dev/sda1]; do
```

try

```
while [ -b /dev/sda1 ]; do
```